# Trouble setting up TesseractOCR with Conan (& cmake)

Tags: c++, shell, cmake, tesseract, conan

I've been looking at the Conan 2 documentations, issues and threads, but I cannot manage to get Tesseract working with Conan. Let me show you my setup:

```bash
App
└── main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
conanfile.txt
```

`main.cpp` is the most basic PoC I could come up with:

```cpp
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>

int main(void) {
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
    return 0;
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

# --------------------------------- Setup project config
set(PROJECT_NAME foo)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# --------------------------------- Set project flags and optimization
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g3 -O0 -W -Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g0 -O3")

# --------------------------------- Fetch sources
set(SOURCES App/main.cpp)

# --------------------------------- Fetch dependencies
find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Tesseract_LIBRARIES: ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "Tesseract_VERSION: ${Tesseract_VERSION}")

# --------------------------------- Build binary
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/App
    ${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

And finally my `conanfile.txt` (`Leptonica` is a direct dependecy of `Tesseract`):

```
[requires]
tesseract/5.3.0
leptonica/1.82.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

Finally I just run the following commands (I usually do it with cmake then make, [but these are the exact commands from the documentation](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html#id5)):

```bash
conan install . --output-folder=build/ --build=missing
# [...]
# Install finished successfully

cmake -B build/ -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
# [...]
# -- Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS: /Users/foo/.conan2/p/b/tesse4be5a6b24f5df/p/include
# -- Tesseract_LIBRARIES: Tesseract::libtesseract
# -- Tesseract_VERSION: 5.3.0
# [...]
# -- Configuring done (0.9s)
# -- Generating done (0.0s)
# -- Build files have been written to: /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build

cmake --build build/ -j 4 -v
# [...]
# Change Dir: '/Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build'
# Run Build Command(s): /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.0/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/make -f Makefile -j4
# /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.0/bin/cmake -S/Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract -B/Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
# /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build/CMakeFiles /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/toto.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/toto.dir/depend
# cd /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/build/CMakeFiles/toto.dir/DependInfo.cmake "--color="
# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/toto.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/toto.dir/build
# [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/toto.dir/App/main.cpp.o
# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -I/Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/App -I/Users/foo/.conan2/p/b/tesse4be5a6b24f5df/p/include -stdlib=libc++ -stdlib=libc++ -g3 -O0 -W -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++20 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/toto.dir/App/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/toto.dir/App/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/toto.dir/App/main.cpp.o -c /Users/foo/Desktop/test_tesseract/App/main.cpp
# [100%] Linking CXX executable toto
# /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/toto.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -stdlib=libc++ -stdlib=libc++ -g3 -O0 -W -Wall -Wextra -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/toto.dir/App/main.cpp.o -o toto 
# ld: Undefined symbols:
#   tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI(), referenced from:
#       _main in main.cpp.o
#   tesseract::TessBaseAPI::~TessBaseAPI(), referenced from:
#       _main in main.cpp.o
# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
# make[2]: *** [toto] Error 1
# make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/toto.dir/all] Error 2
# make: *** [all] Error 2
```

At first I had an error where `#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>` in the `main.cpp` was not found, but that was just my fault, I forgot to link the library trough the `CMakeLists.txt`.

When I fixed that, I just cannot manage to get a `-L`, `-I`, or even `-l` in the build commands (looking with `-v` verbose mode), I just get undefined symbol errors.

To try and force at least a `-l` I tried setting the `target_link_libraries()` in the `CMakeLists.txt`, like so:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES}
)
```

This yields the same result, and finally I manually forced it to write `-ltesseract` with the following:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES}
    tesseract
)
```

This actually works and appends a the `-l` at the end, but I get an even worse error:

```
ld: library 'tesseract' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

For reference I am on arm64 architecture (MacOS), but I don't see why that would be the problem.

Comment: It is possible (and recommended) to use Github issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues for getting support from the Conan team, specially if the issue requires interacting, asking further details, etc, it is better suited there than in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conan takes into account the build type (Release/Debug/...)

By default the `conan profile detect` command sets the configuration for `build_type=Release`, I was building my cmake with the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` flag.

Conan setup everything in the a path dedicated to the Release and cmake was looking in the path dedicated to Debug.

Switching to `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to link tesseract library obviously. Exposing include directory of tesseract makes pre-processor happy, but not the linker.

Prefer to use modern CMake, and rely on CMake imported target like a good citizen, instead of these ugly `Tesseract_*` CMake variables. It's so easy to miss stuff like interface definitions, interface features etc, while CMake target carries all this information:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(foo LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)

add_executable(bar App/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE Tesseract::libtesseract)
target_compile_features(bar PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
```

Comment: This does not fix it for me, I'm getting a `fatal error: 'tesseract/baseapi.h' file not found` error when I use this exact `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: It works fine for me, and tests of conancenter are exactly doing this, so there is something else wrong in your setup you didn't tell us, like a corrupted CMake cache or something else.